# Free AOT Java compiler

Tags: java, compiler-construction, aot

Does anyone know some free AOT Java compiler? I have found just one - http://gcc.gnu.org/java/.

Comment: why would you want to use one?

Comment: Users don't need to install JRE, faster execution, bytecode protection. So why not?

Comment: Users won't need to install a JRE, but it won't execute faster or protect anything.

Comment: http://www.excelsior-usa.com/articles/java-to-exe.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5869665/how-to-create-native-binaries-for-your-java-app || http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16360691/compiling-java-into-native-code

Comment: as of Java 9 you have the `jaotc` AoT compiler right in the JDK https://stackoverflow.com/q/46579565/995714 https://www.infoworld.com/article/3192105/java/java-9s-aot-compiler-use-at-your-own-risk.html anyway this is more suitable on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5):

https://www.excelsiorjet.com/

As of now, it fully supports Java SE 8 and the Standard Edition is free (but only supports 32-bit Windows and Linux.)

Comment: this is now dead

Answer (score 2):

[GCJ](http://gcc.gnu.org/java/) , as you've already noted, is probably your best option. If you're looking for something that runs on Windows you'll need to setup a [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) or [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) environment that runs the GCC.

[JNC](http://jnc.mtsystems.ch/) is an old one that may still work, it was built for Java 1.5 and is based on the GCC.

Comment: Update: GCJ is dead

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how finished it is, but this project uses LLVM and can AOT compile Java and .NET

http://vmkit.llvm.org/