# How to distribute a java program?

Tags: java

I wrote my own java program, but I don't know how to distribute it. After making 'Clean and Build' (from Netbeans) a .jar file is created for me. Do I have to distribute that or do some procedure to create an .exe file?

Comment: What kind of program is it? Is it a server application? Is it a desktop application? Docker images are a ni e way to distribute server applications

Comment: It is a desktop application

Comment: ^ So Swing/AWT or JavaFX

Comment: What are So Swing/AWT and JavaFX?

Comment: Swing/AWS and JavaFX are Java packages for building graphical user interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

Java .jar files are runnable on any Java Virtual Machine. It is a design choice that allows your .jar to be portable.

Comment: But every time I downloaded a java program I never used a .jar file, but I have ever used an .exe file in a folder

Comment: Not only are .jar files runnable on any JVM, they can contain almost any possible supporting files, including dependency modules the code depends on, config files, data files, etc...pretty much anything.

Comment: Since .jar files are a little foreign to regular uses, I think they are often wrapped in a native application just to make people feel better and give them something that acts like other native apps.  For example, a .jar file isn't going to have a nice icon.  I've never had to deal with this.  I assume there are packages that can create the right wrappers for all the common platforms, but that's just a guess.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5869665/how-to-create-native-binaries-for-your-java-app