# Compiling java into native code?

Tags: java, compiler-construction, native

I'm trying to find a java compiler that I can use to compile my java code into native binaries on different operating systems. I have heard of the GNU Compiler for Java but I can't seem to find a download for that and I think it's dead anyway. Are there any good up-to-date compilers out there that I can use to compile java code into a .exe and a .app or anything or can you tell me how to get the GNU Compiler for Java.

Comment: Why do you want to do this - what problem do you hope to solve?

Comment: Also can you tell me how I can improve on asking these questions I'm a little bit new to this website and I'm not very good at asking questions.

Comment: To keep my programs as closed source as possible

Comment: You could use an obfuscator such as [ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/) to make it harder to decompile your code.

Comment: Yes but that still doesn't keep it as closed source as I'd like

Comment: This Question lists some alternatives: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4035538/is-gnus-java-compiler-gcj-dead

Comment: I also want to try just for the point of trying to do it

Comment: Closed source is about licensing ... not about whether people can reverse engineer your code.

Comment: It's for personal use and for sharing with my friends. I just want to give it a go.

Comment: An alternative might be a **code obfuscator** mangling the java names and such.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019724/free-aot-java-compiler

Answer (score 5):

GNU Compiler for the Java can be found at http://gcc.gnu.org/install/binaries.html

And you may try the following tools:

- JET: http://www.excelsior-usa.com/jet.html
- Exe4j: http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/exe4j/overview.html

Answer (score -1):

[gcj](http://gcc.gnu.org/java/) is a part of gcc.

Although judging by it's support for "some 1.5 additions" it is out of date.
Why are you bothering though? You can setup an installer that updates the jre instead.

Comment: What do you mean you can setup an installer that updates the jre instead.

Comment: http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/

Comment: launch4j only wraps the jar in an exe it is still extractable to a normal jar

Comment: I know, I was stating that something like launch4j would be a better option than native compiling. If you absolutely have to have native code then develop using c++. Java wasn't made for it.